Get Country code and mobile number from Azure ADB2C MFA number used to get OTP separately in token claim using Custom Policy
I am using Custom Policy. I need to get Country code and mobile number from Azure ADB2C MFA number  used to get OTP separately in token claim. I can get them as a single unit for e.g. (+91345234223) but I want this as (+91 345234223) with a space or any other separator. Or Even if country code is returned in one claim and number in other claim.
I tried getting MFA number as (+91 345234223) but got (+91345234223).

You could use the GetNationalNumberAndCountryCodeFromPhoneNumberString with CallingCode parameter transformation to split the phone number into two claims.

I tried this but was not able to get result. Can you please elaborate more how to make this work.

What did you try? What error did you get?
